# Leak canary detecting leaks but I dont know how the leak is occuring

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, sdk, leakcanary

I am getting the following leak from leak canary. But I dont know what is the reason.

I also cannot replicate the leak.. The leak occurs randomly so I am not able to trace the leak. Here, I get leak of androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService. I also get leaks of HeapAnalyzerService of lean canary frequently.

Once leak of HeapAnalyzerService is detected, leak detection of HeapAnalyzerService is notified every minute.

```
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.content.res.ResourcesImpl class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static ResourcesImpl.mAppContext
│                           ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.app.ContextImpl instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 2.4 kB in 47 objects
│    mOuterContext instance of androidx.work.impl.foreground.
│    SystemForegroundService
│    ContextImpl.mOuterContext is an instance of androidx.work.impl.foreground.
│    SystemForegroundService
│    ↓ ContextImpl.mOuterContext
│                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
╰→ androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because androidx.work.impl.
​     foreground.SystemForegroundService received Service#onDestroy() callback
​     and Service not held by ActivityThread)
​     Retaining 1.1 kB in 40 objects
​     key = 478fcfc2-3555-4080-806b-6544da5600ba
​     watchDurationMillis = 179862
​     retainedDurationMillis = 174859
​     mApplication instance of com.application.main.MyApp
​     mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
```

Could anybody tell me what may be the cause of this leak?